# Fullcalendar 4.3.1 - Set start of display interval for Timeline view

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, angular8, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to create a view for trimesters/quarters but when I set the duration  like this:

```
views = {
  trimester: {
    ...
    type: 'resourceTimeline',
    duration: { months: 3 }
    ...
  }
}
```

It displays the 3 month interval begining at the current month. I want to make it start at the begining of each trimester (months 1, 4, 7 & 10). The start month calculation is as follows:

```
let startMonth = (Math.ceil(month / 3) * 3) - 2;
```

But I cant find a way to change the interval in the fullcalendar component. It must change when the view is selected because I have other views that won't use the same interval.

I have tried setting the `defaultDate` but it sets for all the views. I have tried changing the `visibleRange` but nothing changed...

Anyone has any idea how to do that?

Comment: `visibleRange` won't do anything because you used `duration`. They're incompatible (which is obvious when you think about it carefully). If you want to use `visibleRange` then get rid of `duration`.

Comment: @ADyson I removed the `duration` and the `visibleRange` worked but now I can't go to the next/previous months. Any workaround for that?

Comment: Need to see your actual code really before I can help easily. Thanks.